# REACT JS reset integer counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, react-state-management

I have this function that gets data from a service using a fetch api call and waits for the response using async and await. If the response isn't null, it loads a react component and passes the fetched data to the component, it uses react state to manage data content.
Because of the wait, i had to introduce an integer counter to help me manage the react page. So the integer counter is initialized to 0 and only increments if the response from fetch call isn't null. So i keep showing a progress bar as long as the counter is 0. Once the data state changes, the integer counter is incremented and the page loads the a new react component with the fetched data.

```
function CheckDeliveries(){
    const [deliveries, setDeliveries] = useState(null);
    const urlAPpend = "delivery/findByCustomerId/";
    let userid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User"))["userId"];
    const httpMethod = 'GET';
    let token = localStorage.getItem("Token");
    
    console.error('RELOAD >>>>>>', reload);

    if(reload < 1){
        makeApiAuthCallsWithVariable(userid,urlAPpend,httpMethod,token).then(
            data  => {
                if (data !== null) {
                    //console.log("Api response: Data "+JSON.stringify(data));
                    setDeliveries(data);
                    reload++
                }else{
                    console.error('Response not ok', data);
                }
            }
        )
    }

    if(reload >= 1 && deliveries !== null){
        reload = 0;
        console.error('RELOAD AllDeliveryDiv >>>>>>', reload);
        return (<AllDeliveryDiv obj = {deliveries} />);
    }else if(reload >= 1 && deliveries === null){
        reload = 0;
        console.error('RELOAD MakeDeliveryDiv >>>>>>', reload);
        return (<MakeDeliveryDiv />);
    }else if(reload === 0){
        return ( <ProgressBar striped variant="primary" now={value}/>);
    }
}
```

**My Question**

1. I have tried using a boolean state instead of integer counter but the page gets into an infinite loop whenever i update the boolean state. Is there a way i can implement this boolean state in without experiencing the infinite loop ?
2. After i fetch the data, and reset the counter to 0. I log the value before reset and after reset and i get 1 and 0 respectively. But when i call this function again without reloading the entire page, counter value remains 1 even after i had reset it earlier. How do i resolve this?
3. Any better way to implement this, please share.

Comment: Where is `reload` declared and initialized in your code?

Comment: Don't you mean await response.json() ? awaiting something you already have is pointless.

Comment: Also what's the point of passing `deliveries` as a prop for `<MakeDeliveryDiv obj={deliveries} />`, when `deliveries` is `null`?

Comment: @secan i declared reload above the react class, as if i declare it inside the function, it results to an infinite loop because of the if statement.

Comment: @Woody yes, response.json()

Comment: You really should... no, _must_ not use global variables with React components, nor do remote calls during a render outside an `useEffect` hook!

Comment: Are you trying to call this API just once or are you trying to poll it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to really tell what you're going for with `reload`, so that's why I left the whole `MakeDeliveryDiv` stuff out, but this would load data from your endpoint when the component is first mounted using the [`useEffect` side effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
function CheckDeliveries() {
  const [deliveries, setDeliveries] = useState(null);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const userid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User"))["userId"];
    const token = localStorage.getItem("Token");
    makeApiAuthCallsWithVariable(
      userid,
      "delivery/findByCustomerId/",
      "GET",
      token,
    ).then((data) => {
      setDeliveries(data);
      setLoaded(true);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!loaded) {
    return <ProgressBar striped variant="primary" now={value} />;
  }
  if (deliveries === null) {
    return <>Data not OK.</>;
  }

  return <AllDeliveryDiv obj={deliveries} />;
}
```